# SQL ORDER BY statement retrieving less records

Tags: sql, db2-400, rpgle

I have a program that runs embedded SQL to retrieve data from four joined files. When I try to order the records by a field (not the key fields), the number of records retrieved drops from 9,999 (the maximum for a subfile) to 113. I ran the same SQL statement (both with and without the ORDER BY clause) on SQL Server and they both returned the same number of records (more than 9,999). Has anyone else encountered this issue, or am I just trying to do too much?

```
SELECT  cawlaml0.WMAWID,cawlabl0.WBBLCD,cawlaml0.WMCODE,
        SUBSTRING(cawlael0.WEFKEY,1,32) as WEFKEY32,
        SUBSTRING(cawlael0.WETKEY,1,32) as WETKEY32,
        cawlaml0.WMEFFR,cawlaml0.WMEFTO,cawlaml0.WMEFLG,
        cawlaml0.WMUSED,cawladl0.WDEAAL,cawladl0.WDLORG,
        cawladl0.WDLBAL,cawlael0.WEAWLN,cawladl0.WDAWPR

FROM cawlaml0

INNER JOIN cawlabl0
        on cawlaml0.WMAWID = cawlabl0.WBAWID
INNER JOIN cawlael0
        on cawlaml0.WMAWID = cawlael0.WEAWID
LEFT OUTER JOIN cawladl0
        on cawlaml0.WMAWID = cawladl0.WDAWID


WHERE
         // The '@' fields are user input fields.
        (cawlael0.WEFKEY = :@WEFKEY or :@WEFKEY = ' ') and
        (cawlael0.WETKEY = :@WETKEY or :@WETKEY = ' ') and
        (cawlabl0.WBBLCD = :@WBBLCD or :@WBBLCD = ' ') and
        (cawlaml0.WMCODE = :@WMCODE or :@WMCODE = ' ') and
         cawlael0.WEAWLN = cawladl0.WDAWLN

ORDER BY WEFKEY32;
```

Comment: The cawlael0.WEAWLN = cawladl0.WDAWLN condition in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. If you want a LEFT JOIN, move that condition to the ON clause.

Comment: @Nate Huff maybe you have 1 or more records with Null fields, the SQL interpreter can handle it, but the RPGLE pgm doesn't know how to handle it...

Comment: Are you checking `sqlstate` or `sqlcode` for errors in your RPG program? That could provide some information. Check your job log, are there are errors or warnings reported?

Comment: @jarlh Thank you. I completely forgot I could join on multiple fields.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Yes. I haven't run into any records that gave a bad SQLState. There are no errors or warnings. The program functions as expected except for the lack of records when the ORDER BY clause is introduced.

Comment: @Nifriz The fields I am trying to order by can't be null. If I use the user input fields, I can still get records that won't show up. It is just when I try to retrieve all records that it will do this.

Comment: @NateHuff There is no reason that `ORDER BY` should filter records. This might be something you have to go to IBM to get resolved.

Comment: By any chance, do you happen to have any logical files that access one or more of these tables that happens to filter out records as well?  It's speculative but someone mentioned SQL using a logical like this before.  They changed their code before I could verify it though.

Comment: @Player1st I don't believe so. I will try using the physical files instead and see if I get a different result.

Comment: @NateHuff I don't know that you can force it to use the physical files. The SQL query optimizer is the one that decides to use the logical file behind the scenes. You can probably use VisualExplain to analyze the query and see if it is using something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the issue was not with the SQL itself but with some of the data. While the SQL could retrieve all of the records, my fetch statement was the cause of the error. I was putting the fields into a screen and failed to realize there was a record (the 114th one to be exact) had bad dates (WMEFFR and WMEFTO) that were outside the bounds of valid.

Fetch Statement:

```
EXEC SQL
     FETCH NEXT FROM R1
       INTO :WMAWID,:WBBLCD,:WMCODE,:WEFKEY32,:WETKEY32,
       :WMEFFRA,:WMEFTOA,:WMEFLG,:WMUSED,:WDEAAL,
       :WDLORG,:WDLBAL,:WEAWLN,:WESTAT,:WEAWEX;
```

SQL Table:

[image: HUFFN Data Table]

Since the record was so far down in the unsorted list, I didn't actually encounter it until I tried to sort, so this one is on me.

Thank you all for your answers!